# How to show only folders with specific files using QTreeView and QFileSystemModel?

Tags: qt, qtreeview, qfilesystemmodel

I have a problem filtering specific folder using QTreeView and QFileSystemModel.

I set my root QFileSystemModel to a specific folder - this works. But I want to show just folders that contain `.jpg` files. Is this possible?

I filter `.jpg` files and that works, but my QTreeView shows all folders, even those that do not have `.jpg` files. So if the user tries to open some folder without `.jpg` files, nothing happens.

How can I hide those folders?

Note: below there are part of the code.

```
QStringList filterTypeFile;
filterTypeFile.append("*.jpg");
this->m_pModelTreeViewImage->setNameFilters(filterTypeFile);
this->m_pModelTreeViewImage->setNameFilterDisables(false);

this->ui->treeViewImages->setModel(this->m_pModelTreeViewImage);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bad news, I'm afraid: You're going to have to implement this yourself if you want that sort of behaviour.  File system readers just aren't set up to do this sort of thing.

There's a reason for that, too.  Hiding files is commonly supported because it's fast and easy - either a filename matches your regex or it doesn't.  Hiding directories (or making them unopenable - same difference) is a lot trickier.  You can't just look at the directory name; you have to crawl the file system, looking for openable files.  And hard drive access is *slow*.  Imagine that your user is looking at a directory very close to the root of your file system - you'd have to crawl through *everything*.  And then, if the filter changed, you'd have to do it all again.

Also consider:  The established pattern for this is to only hide files, and never hide directories.  This is probably as a result of the technical difficulties described above, but it has become a standard UI behaviour.  So if a user comes across a file system viewer that isn't showing all the folders they expect (or if they can't open certain folders, *seemingly* at random), they're going to assume something's broken.

That said, if there's a good reason to do it anyway, you could probably reimplement QFileSystemModel to do what you want (or, failing that, you could certainly get an AbstractModel subclass to behave like you've described).  Your users will acclimate, especially if there's a good reason for the new behaviour.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks @Xavier Holt! I understood everything about your answer and really makes sense. By the way, i forgot to write one more note in my ask... In Qt documentation, at QFileSystemModel::setFilter() talks: **Note that the filter you set should always include the QDir::AllDirs enum value, otherwise QFileSystemModel won't be able to read the directory structure.**.

I will study if is really necessary to implement this behaviour. Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: Well, i'm trying to implement my own QTreeView. I have problems because i don't know how to select first QModelIndex in my QTreeView. Note: i'm using QFileSytemModel.

Comment: @AdrianoLeal - This is just a guess, since I've only used Qt's MVC stuff tangentially, but I'd try to get all the "structure" related information (that includes the "first" model index) through the QFileSystemModel rather than the view.  It looks like Qt views are really only designed to handle UI operations, while organization is taken care of in the models themselves.

Answer (score -1):

You should derive from `QSortFilterProxyModel` and reimplement the 
`virtual bool   filterAcceptsRow ( int source_row, const QModelIndex & source_parent ) const`
function. Something like this

```
bool JPGFilter::filterAcceptsRow(int source_row, const QModelIndex &source_parent) const
{
   QFileSystemModel *fs = static_cast<QFileSystemModel*>(sourceModel());
   QModelIndex i = fs->index(source_row, 0, source_parent);
   bool accept=false;
   if( fs->hasChildren(i) ){
     for( int j=0; j<fs->rowCount(i); j++  )
       if( fs->fileInfo(fs->index(j,0,i)).suffix()=="jpg" ){
         accept=true;
         break;
       }
   }
   return accept;
}
```

I haven't tried this on my own. It is slow, but should work.

Comment: This solution seems a priory elegant, but it doesn't work because the QFileSystemModel seems to contain only the expended QModelIndex. It is not possible to recursively remove the empty directories, but maybe only the leaf ones.